# Populating the dropdownlist from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a drop downlist control and a button control in my asp.net web page.
I'm populating my drop down list from data base.

I Have this method to populate the drop down list.

```
     public void fillDD()
{
    SqlDataReader rd = new ViewBorrowersOP().getTitlestoCombo();
    while (rd.Read())
    {
        DDTitle.Items.Add((String)rd[0]);
    }
}
```

This is my business layer. Method for that.

```
     public SqlDataReader getTitlestoCombo()
{
    string query1 = "EXEC getAllBKTitles";
    return new DataAccessLayer().executeQuerys(query1);
}
```

I'm calling the method in page load event.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fillDD();
}
```

I'm clicking button to populate a data grid. It works fine. And the code to populate the drop downlist works fine too. But each time When I click button to populate grid view or  each time I refresh the Page the dropdown list is populating again with same items.

```
   Let's say for the first time when I load the page the drop down list is populated with following items. 


    CAT
    DOG 
    BAT
```

If I click the button or if the page reloads it will again populate ,when this happens three times my drop down list looks like this.

```
    CAT
    DOG 
    BAT
    CAT
    DOG 
    BAT
    CAT
    DOG 
    BAT
```

How to prevent this happening?

Comment: Hope the answer will help. let me know for any further help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the below with

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fillDD();
    }
```

with

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!IsPostBack)
   {
    fillDD();
   }
}
```

Comment: please mark it as answers, so that others can get benefit out of it